# Template in union member - Declaration does not declare anything

Tags: c++, templates, unions

I need to create a "node" class which is either able to store its content (of type `T`) or a `nullptr` (representing an empty node).

This node must have metadata (like its age) both when it stores something and nothing.

I came up with this (simplified) code:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct Node
{
    union T_or_null {
        T;
        std::nullptr_t;
    };

    int age;
    T_or_null content;

    Node(T_or_null argContent)
        : age(0),
          content(argContent)
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    Node<int> a(0);
    Node<int> b(nullptr);

    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the error `main.cpp:5:3: error: declaration does not declare anything [-fpermissive]`

Gcc seems to understand that I am trying to create an union of anything and `nullptr_t` (which is part of anything), but it should be an union of `int` and `nullptr_t` in this context, nothing more.

Do I misunderstand how templates work or do I need to do something differently?

Comment: How are you ever going to use `content` other than initialize it if its members don't have names?

Comment: Also, take a look at [`std::optional<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional).

Comment: You need names for the members in the union `T_or_null`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Union members need a name, too:

```
union T_or_null {
    T value;
    std::nullptr_t null;
};
```

But they also require manual bookkeeping to handle correctly, so I suggest you ditch the union and switch to `std::optional` to model nullability:

```
template <typename T>
struct Node
{
    int age;
    std::optional<T> content;

    Node(std::optional<T> argContent)
        : age(0),
          content(argContent)
    {
    }
};
```